# Can Breaker Bay Grid be used to reduce cost of other Regions?

Tags: android-netrunner

[Breaker Bay Grid](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08040) states:

> The rez cost of cards in this server is lowered by 5.
>
> Limit 1 region per server.

Can this be used to lower the cost of rezzing another Region (and then trashing Breaker Bay Grid to satisfy "Limit 1 region per server") like [SanSan City Grid](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01092), or must I trash the first Region before rezzing the second?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot because upgrades are always installed un-rezzed from your hand.

In order to put [SanSan City Grid](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01092) onto a server you first have to discard [Breaker Bay Grid](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08040). Therefore by the time you can rez SanSan City Grid you no longer have the effect of Breaker Bay Grid.

Also note the reason is because you aren't allowed to have two regions installed and the time to discard the other one is before the new one is played per the rules.

Comment: Exactly correct. Just because you are installing the cards face down doesn't change the fact that they are both "regions" - as soon as you install the second region, the first is trashed, just as if you installed over an asset or agenda.

Comment: Yep, as clarified [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/840474/unofficial-faq-list): There may be a maximum of one region installed per server (per the text on region cards) and having two or more in a server simultaneously (rezzed or unrezzed) would constitute maintaining an illegal game state.